# how to add json jar lib to java using environment variable

Tags: java, json, environment-variables

i have prepared a java file that uses Json library so i downloaded a JSON library from "http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json_simple-1.1-all.zip&can=2&q="
but very confuse where to place it, so that my java file can detect Json library.

I tried to place the lib "json_simple-1.1" inside "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\lib"
but not working yet.

How can i solve the problem using environment variable or any other means where i don't need to set path on comman prompt?

Comment: are you using an IDE (like NetBeans or Eclipse)? In that case take a look at your build path under project settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways you can include jar file to run your program.

```
java -classpath "{yourpath}/json.jar:." my.package.Program
java -cp "{yourpath}/json.jar:." my.package.Program
```

Other way is to set env variable `java.ext.dirs`.

```
-Djava.ext.dirs=jarDirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it beside your jar (in case you package your application into a jar) and add a link to it in your manifest, e.g.:

your jar contains a META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file which has (besides others) this entry:

> Class-Path: json_simple-1.1.jar

More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;<path to libraries folder>
```